# insert multiple users in mysql database using awk

Tags: mysql, bash, awk

Currently, I have a usrpwd.txt file with users and passwords separated by 'space'. I wish to add these users to my mysql server and change their privileges. Since there are 2000 users, it becomes unpractical to add them manually. I tried to use awk in a bash script:

```
awk '{mysql -u root -proot -e "CREATE USER '\''"$1"'\''@'\''%'\'' IDENTIFIED BY '\''"$2"'\'';"}' ./conf/usrpwd.txt ;
```

Unfortunately, the users are not being added. No error is reported.
Regards, Andre

Comment: I found an alternative way, unfortunately cannot answer to question yet, so I leave it in this comment: 

#!/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read -r value1 value2 remainder
do
mysql -u root -proot -e "CREATE USER '"$value1"'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"$value2"';"
mysql -u root -proot -e "GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON *.* TO '"$value1"'@'%';"
done < ./conf/usrpwd.txt

Comment: If you add concise, testable sample input and expected output I'm sure someone will be able to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct wouldn't be to solve this in awk, but anyway, here it is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
   cmd = sprintf("mysql -u root -p root -h localhost -e \"CREATE USER '%s'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '%s'\"", $1, $2)
   if ((cmd | getline line) > 0)
      print line
   close(cmd)
}
```

You can call this like:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk usrpwd.txt
```

or you could put this in a bash script, if you wanted to.

Comment: you may suggest `print cmd`; and then `awk -f tst.awk usrpwd.txt | bash`